# Excel - display as percentage, but keep properties as general or custom

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, formatting, cells

Based on the image below that is how I want numbers to be displayed - as a percentage. But I don't want the properties to be listed as a percentage I want it to be listed as general "no specific format." When I change numbers from percentage to general it changes the percentage style. Is there any way to format this in "format cells" under custom?

[image: Display]

Comment: Its easy using the Format cells setting. What do you mean changing it from general to percentage changes the percentage style? Right now, I have mine looking exactly like the above image.

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that you would like Excel to show you percentages with 4 decimal places.  To me the easiest/quickest way to achieve this result is to format the column as Percentage and change the Decimal Places to 4.

The screenshot below is from me right clicking the cell and saying format.

[image: Percentage with 4 decimal places]